# Why RenderScript 4.0 sample like "Balls" in eclipse do not generate the ScriptC_balls.java (s)?

Tags: eclipse, renderscript

I run the RenderScript 4.0 sample like "Balls" in eclipse, but the project do not  generate the ScriptC_balls.java (s)
My ADT is 18,sdk is 15(4.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of info to go on here but RenderScript and ADT are very sensitive to order and the autogen aspect can easily be confused. If simply cleaning the project doesn't work, try checking to make sure that the

```
#pragma rs java_package_name(name)
```

corresponds with the package the .rs file is in. Sometimes when importing the sample RenderScript projects, the package names don't end up right. I usually just create a new project and import the source files and plan on fiddling with the package names to get it right.

Comment: My project there is #pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.android.rs.balls)'

Comment: And now there is a new problem "<built-in>:2:10: fatal: 'rs_core.rsh' file not found". lol

Comment: That suggests to me that your android-sdk is messed up somehow. I would try removing it and reinstalling the sdk.

Comment: my package names is the same however script files are not generated automatically. using min sdk 14 and the example hello compute

Answer (score 0):

All Right.
Please Check your AndroidManifest.xml at first.
Maybe here are some problems when you set.
`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />` 
the version should be better larger than 15.